# Automator: rename files fixing the gaps in numbers 1,2,3,5,6 -> 1,2,3,4,5

Tags: automator, batch-rename

I have a huge bunch of scanned files (before OCR) and I want the Automator (Yosemite) to fix the gaps in files numbers: some pages was duplicated and after deletion the duplication there are gaps in numbering like:

Scan1, Scan2, Scan3, Scan5, Scan6.

I need the Automator take a specified folder with consecutive numbering in file names and fix these gaps.

I tried to find something similar but failed. Any ideas would be highle appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Windows Batch script (You should change the "Scan!i!.jpg" to something you would like, !i! part is unchanged and the workdir):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set i=1
cd C:\workdir
for /f %%f in ('dir /b .\') do (
  echo renaming "%%f" to "Scan!i!.jpg"
  ren "%%f" "Scan!i!.jpg"
  set /A i=!i!+1
)
ENDLOCAL
set "i="
```

- This will rename all the files in a folder in sequence, like
  `Scan1.jpg`, `Scan2.jpg`, `Scan3.jpg`.
- Paste it to notepad and save it as .bat file
- Try it on some junk first and see if it is what you need.

Here is a solution for Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
workdir=/home/user
i=1
for f in `ls $workdir`
do
  echo renaming $f to "Scan$i.jpg"
  mv $workdir/$f $workdir/Scan$i.jpg
  i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Just save as `script.sh` or something, `chmod +x script.sh` and run like `./script.sh`. Make sure to specify the correct directory and filename

Comment: will it work on Mac?

Comment: No, sorry, it's for windows. Will have to change it for MAC. Please specify that you are using Mac in your question so that people would know;)

Comment: Automator is a tool for Mac only %)